# Prevent Excel from defaulting "True" and "False" to boolean

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel document defaults all `True` and `False` strings to `TRUE` and `FALSE`, which it then treats as a boolean value and this is failing in my macro.

I can `right click -> format cells -> select text`, but I don't know which cells users will use, so this method will not work.

Is there a global method to disable this automatic conversion or perhaps a method using VBA?

Comment: Can't you change the AutoCorrect options in Excel?

Comment: @doubleDown, Your method seems to be the easiest way, but I see no option that specifies `True` and `False` are to be changed into their Boolean counterparts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved the problem through another method and just formatted all cells as `Text`

Comment: thanks man. this is what i was looking for.  you saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

Make a second column. Use `=IF(A1,"T","F")` (where A1 is the boolean value) and use the new column instead.

I don't know how your macro works, but you might be able to use that in your macro instead.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no actual formula in the cell then examine the `Formula` property (rather than the `Value` property) and you should get a String containing "True" or "False" as appropriate

If there is a formula in the cell then use `CStr` to change the result of examining the `Value` property from a Boolean value to a String value - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264697.aspx